suspected stars and bars problem considered incorrect, in need for some further insight
Consider a set of $12$ students, who each will enroll in one and only one of three classes, in how many arrays can the students end up if we want no class to have zero students?
This problem seems easy enough: Obtain the population for each class $A$, $B$, $C$ such that $1\leq A, B, C$ and $A+B+C = 12$. We solve a stars and bars problem by changing the variables, $a=A-1$, $b=B-1$, $c=C-1$, then $a+b+c=9$.
Now, this gives ${11 \choose 2}$ possible arrays for the students to be found in. What's left of me to do? Did I account the fact that no student can share two or more classes already?

Your computations are incorrect, as you are assuming students to be identical objects, whereas persons are surely distinct !
There are two ways you could approach the problem:

The first is to use Stirling numbers of the second kind which puts distinguishable objects into identical non-empty bins, and then permute the bins (because the classes are distinct), thus $3!{{12}\brace 3} = 519156$

Or if you not have yet graduated to learning Stirling numbers of the second kind, (or don't have tables of Stirling numbers handy) just use good old PIE (Principle of inclusion-exclusion) to get $3^{12} - \binom31 2^{12} + \binom32 1^{12}=519156$
i.e. |All possible allocations| - |one class guaranteed vacant| + |two classes guaranteed vacant|


PS:
All this, of course, is assumng that enrollments of students to classes are done uniformly at random, which may or may not be true in reality !
